# UIImageView transparent black on a cell bug (Objective-C)

Tags: objective-c, uiimageview, cell, collectionview

I have a UIImageView installed on my cell, it is transparent black, but when I scroll the CollectionView and I raise my UIImageView but there is always more to transprence.
See picture :

1 - I is not even scroll
[image: I is not even scroll]

2 - After a scroll
[image: After a scroll]

My code :

```
    - (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"pictureCell";

    MSContestListCollectionViewCell *cell = (MSContestListCollectionViewCell *)[self.collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.titleContest.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
    cell.titleContest.minimumScaleFactor = 0.5;

    cell.pictureImageView.layer.cornerRadius = 5;
    cell.pictureImageView.clipsToBounds = YES;

    cell.titleView.layer.cornerRadius = 5;
    cell.titleView.clipsToBounds = YES;

    switch (_segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex) {
        case 0: {
            NSDictionary *searchResult = [self.readArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.item];
            NSString *stringImage = [searchResult objectForKey:@"featuredImage"];

            NSString *image = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://srv.mediaswapp.com/%@", stringImage];
            [cell.pictureImageView sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:image]
                                     placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];

            cell.statusContest.text = [searchResult objectForKey:@"status"];

            if ([[searchResult objectForKey:@"status"] isEqualToString:@"PAUSE"]) {
                cell.titleContest.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Concours en pause"];
                /*
                UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(cell.contentView.frame.origin.x, cell.contentView.frame.origin.y, cell.contentView.frame.size.width, cell.contentView.frame.size.height)];
                view.backgroundColor = [[UIColor blackColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.8f];
                view.layer.cornerRadius = 5;
                view.clipsToBounds = YES;
                [cell.contentView addSubview:view];
                 */
                UIImageView *imagecellPause = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(cell.contentView.frame.origin.x, cell.contentView.frame.origin.y, cell.contentView.frame.size.width, cell.contentView.frame.size.height)];
                UIImage *cellImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"cell-pause.png"];
                imagecellPause.image = cellImage;
                [cell.contentView addSubview:imagecellPause];
                UIImageView *imagePause = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(69.5, 69.5, 25, 25)];
                UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Pause Filled-50 (1).png"];
                imagePause.image = image;
                [cell.contentView addSubview:imagePause];
                UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 90, 150, 50)];
                label.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
                label.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Avenir-Book" size:12];
                label.text = [searchResult objectForKey:@"description"];
                label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
                label.minimumScaleFactor = 0.5;
                [cell.contentView addSubview:label];
                UILabel *label2 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 105, 150, 50)];
                label2.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
                label2.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Avenir-Black" size:15];
                label2.text = @"Concours en pause";
                [cell.contentView addSubview:label2];
                cell.titleView.hidden = YES;
            } else {
                cell.titleContest.text = [searchResult objectForKey:@"description"];
            }
            break;
        }
        case 1: {
            NSDictionary *searchResult2 = [self.readArrayWinner objectAtIndex:indexPath.item];
            NSString *stringImage = [searchResult2 objectForKey:@"featuredImage"];

            NSString *image = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://srv.mediaswapp.com/%@", stringImage];
            [cell.pictureImageView sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:image]
                                     placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];

            cell.titleContest.text = [searchResult2 objectForKey:@"description"];
            cell.statusContest.text = [searchResult2 objectForKey:@"status"];

            NSLog(@"le gagnant : %@", [searchResult2 valueForKeyPath:@"winners.name"]);
            break;
        }
        case 2: {
            NSDictionary *searchResult3 = [self.readArrayPhotos objectAtIndex:indexPath.item];
            NSString *stringImage = [searchResult3 objectForKey:@"featuredImage"];

            NSString *image = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://srv.mediaswapp.com/%@", stringImage];
            [cell.pictureImageView sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:image]
                                     placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];

            cell.titleContest.text = [searchResult3 objectForKey:@"description"];
            cell.statusContest.text = [searchResult3 objectForKey:@"status"];
            break;
        }

        default:
            break;
    }

    [_activity stopAnimating];
    _label1.hidden = YES;

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: you need to write this code in below condition  if(cell==nil){ Your code }

Comment: Are you adding the image view multiple times by accident? Each time the cell is setup/requested/reused?

Answer (score 0):

Your `CellForRowAtIndexPath` should never contain `addSubView`, since everytime the cell is reloaded it will add the view. Thats why it keeps getting darker, it just adds view onto view.

Instead you should subclass your `UICollectionViewCell` and add the view in the subclass.

Comment: Okay thank you, and in my subclasses, according to what I have to add my subview ?

Comment: Actually, it's OK to add a subview here. But you need to check whether the subview has already been added first. You can use view tags for that. For example, give the image view a tag 42 and then you can do `UIImageView* imageView = [cell viewWithTag:42]; if (!imageView) { /* Create image view and add it */ }`

Comment: this is the same, my code : UIImageView* imageView = [cell viewWithTag:42]; if (!imageView) {
                    imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(cell.contentView.frame.origin.x, cell.contentView.frame.origin.y, cell.contentView.frame.size.width, cell.contentView.frame.size.height)];
                    UIImage *cellImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"cell-pause.png"];
                    imageView.image = cellImage;
                    [cell.contentView addSubview:imageView];
                }

Comment: @victorbill: You also need to set the tag when you create the image view: `imageView.tag = 42;`.